# flatpickr formatting end value after selection

Tags: jquery, datetime, flatpickr

I have the following html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.StartDate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { type = "text", @class = "flatpickrStart form-control", @id = "absenceStartDate", @Required = true })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.StartDate, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EndDate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { type = "text", @class = "flatpickrEnd form-control", @id = "absenceEndDate", @Required = true })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EndDate, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

and script:

```
function InitializeDateTimePickers() {
    $(".flatpickrStart, .flatpickrEnd").flatpickr({
        dateFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy H:i:s",
        enableTime: true,
        weekNumbers: true,
        altInput: true,
        altFormat: "F j, Y - h:i",
        time_24hr: true
    });
}
```

My codepen for example: 
https://codepen.io/andrelange91/pen/YOgwaJ

The selection works fine, but when i have selected a value, 
the value i get seems double in some places.

For example i use the picker to select this: September 21, 2018 - 8:00
the value returned is this: 2121-SepSep-18181818 08:00:0

Is there a way for me to get a proper datetime format for it ? 
First time using this plugin, and i have so far been unable to find a solution.

Comment: No need to write code two times. just write one time `$(".flatpickrStart, .flatpickrEnd").flatpickr({
        dateFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy H:i:s",
        enableTime: true,
        weekNumbers: true,
        altInput: true,
        altFormat: "F j, Y - h:i",
        time_24hr: true
    });`. I hope issue will get resolve. If not convert `class` to `id` and then check

Comment: @AlivetoDie cool, did not know i could do that ^^ thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to write code two times. just write one time

```
$(".flatpickrStart, .flatpickrEnd").flatpickr({ 
   dateFormat: "d-M-y H:i:s", //change format also 
   enableTime: true, 
   weekNumbers: true, 
   altInput: true, 
   altFormat: "F j, Y - h:i", 
   time_24hr: true 
});
```

Your problem will get solved.

Working snippet:- https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VGRWZv

***Note:*** I have changed text outputting code in my link too, check that also.

Comment: Yep, that will work. Seems Flatpickr, does not support dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: @andrelange91  glad to help you :):)